Certain activities during wudu

I was doing wudu when suddenly my mom called so I needed to give a pause for a few seconds and when I came back I did my wudu from where I had paused. Is that okay or should I had done wudu from the beginning?
When doing wudu, lets say when I was cleaning my ears I felt like I should had cleaned my hands better so I quickly cleaned my hands again and then again continued my wudu from cleaning my ears. Is that okay?

Hopefully they were okay as I believe Islam is a simple religion and my wudu wouldn’t be invalid for such minimal reasons.

assalam alaikom
Praise be to Allah.
if the part that you were washing didnt became dry in those few seconds there is no problem so that does not invalidate the wudu as long is not dry
Al-Mirdawi (may Allah have mercy on him) said in Al-Insaf (1/141) regarding doing the actions of Wudu consecutively: “It means not delaying the washing of any part for so long that the part that was washed before it becomes dry. Meaning: within an average timespan
but some scholars like IMAM AHMAD may ALLAH have mercy on him say it depend ont  whatever is customarily regarded as too long of an interruption but it would be diifficult to define it.
2  a brief pause for necessary actions related to purity, even if the body dries in the meantime, does not invalidate wudu, and you can resume from where you left off so Continuity would not be disrupted by such an action so if see dirt in you finger or hands from example  Fatawa ibn Uthaimeen, 4/145-146 (Dar al-Qutni)  https://islamqa.info/en/answers/1/interruption-of-wudu
https://islamqa.info/en/answers/196846/does-pausing-during-wudu-invalidate-it
read those brief articles they adress your situation
AND ALLAH KNOW BEST
